# Regex nothing or some options

Tags: regex, null

I am trying to develop a regular expression to extract this: `PT~MM:SS~EQP>G-G<EQP` from a file.

PT is optional but if it is present it's only valid if it is 1P, 2P, 1EP or 2EP.

So if the example is: `3EP~101:37~POR>4-2<ISL` it shouldn't be matching nothing but I am getting `2EP~101:37~POR>4-2<ISL` as a match.

So far I've tried this:

`(((1|2)P|(1|2)EP)~)?(0{0,1}([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|1[01][0-9]|120)):(0*([0-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-9]))~[A-Z]{3}>[0-9]-[0-9]<[A-Z]{3}`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might what you are looking for `^(?:[12]E?P)?~?\w+?:\w+?~\w+?>\w-\w<\w{3}` (https://regex101.com/r/T8Cy4C/6). Although you did not specified fully what are the requirements for each parts.

Comment: This helped me: (?:[12]E?P)(~?)?(0{0,1}([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|1[01][0-9]|120)):(0*([0-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-9]))~[A-Z]{3}>[0-9]-[0-9]<[A-Z]{3} the problem is that If I have only 89:12~FRA>2-1<ROM it is suposed to appear as a match and it isn't appearing